# Detecting browser on mobile device is wrong

Tags: c#, ios, mobile

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities browserFeatures = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
contextText = contextText.Replace("[[Browser Name]]", browserFeatures.Browser);
contextText = contextText.Replace("[[Browser Version]]", browserFeatures.Version);
```

When browsing my website in Chrome the code above on ipads, iphone, and ipods returns Safari 5.1

It should return Chrome 32.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Is there a better way to get this information?

Comment: Chrome on iOS uses `UIWebView`. It's just a wrapper. And `UIWebView` has Safari as it's user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in how a webpage will show up between Safari for iOS and Chrome for iOS. This is because they both use the same deeper level web view.

As far as I know, there is no way to access whether a user is in Safari or Chrome on iOS - however there should also be no need to know. Treat them as the same thing.

Comment: When displaying a message to the user we want to say something like this. "Your Chrome browser version 25 is out of date. Please update to view our site as intended."

Comment: On iOS however, it won't matter what version of Chrome for iOS they have - the actual webview is the same for any given verion of iOS itself. So if the browser is out of date, you'll mostly likely want to tell your user "Your verion of iOS is out of date. Please update your device"